# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.giulio.client.UtentePass while passing an object between client and server in java

Tags: java, sockets, netbeans, server, client

i'm trying to pass a class object between client and server in two differents java projects, but i get this error:

```
 apr 28, 2022 10:57:46 AM com.giulio.serverdatabase.ServerGestion run
    GRAVE: null
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.giulio.client.UtentePass
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:756)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1984)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2158)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1665)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:459)
        at 
com.giulio.serverdatabase.ServerGestion.run(ServerGestion.java:51)
```

I've alerady make sure that the connection between client and server is created and works fine.

This is the class of the object i want to pass, i've created the class in both programms:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 * @author giuli
 */
public class UtentePass implements Serializable{
       private String Utente, Password;

    public UtentePass(String Utente, String Password) {
        this.Utente = Utente;
        this.Password = Password;
    }

    public UtentePass() {
    }
    
    public String getUtente() {
        return Utente;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UtentePass{" + "Utente=" + Utente + ", Password=" + Password + '}';
    }
    
    

}
```

now those are the client and server classes:

```
public class Client_Class {
    
    public Client_Class(){
    }
    
    public void Client(UtentePass utentePass) {
        
 
        String hostname = "localhost";
        int port = 42768;
 
        try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port)) {
 
            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
                      
            
                ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new 
                           ObjectOutputStream(output);
            
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(utentePass);
                 socket.close();
 
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
 
            System.out.println("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage());
 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
 
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    } 
}
```

And this is the server class:

```
 class ServerGestion extends Thread {
        
        private ServerSocket serverSocket;

        public ServerGestion(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
            this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
        }

    ServerGestion() {}
    
    
    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            
             try {
                 
             while (true) { // una volta servito un client si rimette in attesa         
                  
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                   System.out.println("New client connected");
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    System.out.println("IP: " + socket.getInetAddress().toString());
                    System.out.println("port: " + socket.getPort());
 
                    InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();    
                    ObjectInputStream output = new ObjectInputStream(input);
                  
                    
                    UtentePass utp = new UtentePass(); 
                     utp = (UtentePass) output.readObject();
                        socket.close();
                }
 
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(ServerGestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        
      public void avvia(int port) {
         try  {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            
            System.out.println("Server is listening on port " + port);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                
                (new ServerGestion(serverSocket)).start();
                
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
    
    }
```

I have alerady made the UtentePass class serizable.

Comment: It isn't  in the classpath. You need to make sure it is

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: I can't say as I don't know how you developed or are running. Both sides of the comms need to be able to load the necessary classes

Comment: ok thanks now i know what to search

Comment: Does the class exist on the server?

Comment: @user253751 I' using netbeans, how can i have the same class in two differents projects?

Comment: @MarioPascolat probably can't, but you can make a library used in two other projects.

Comment: @user253751 how can i do it?